# Firefox launcher icon appears twice for own .desktop file

Tags: unity, firefox, launcher

I want to add my own .desktop file to the Unity Launcher. I created `firejailFirefox.desktop` in `~/.local/share/applications/`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=firejailFirefox.desktop
Icon=firefox
Exec=firejail firefox %U
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

Then I go in the Dash (Windows key and typed the name of the application) and drag and drop it to the Unity Launcher. But now the firefox icon appears twice when I click on my `firejailFirefox` Launcher icon. How to get only one icon after starting `firejail firefox` from Launcher?

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.04
Release:    17.04
Codename:   zesty
```

[image]

Comment: Why not make an `alias` in `.bashrc`: ("alias firefox=`firejail firefox %u`") so you launch with `firefox` and it will run in `firejail`

Comment: Another I see `%U` when in my firefox desktop file I see `%u`...

Comment: @George, create an `alias` in .bashrc does not work, if I start firefox through my `firejailFirefox.desktop` Luncher icon. Did you tried it. Maybe `firejailFirefox.desktop` is using a Terminal with different setup.